# Inserting Query String Variables in XML using PHP/curl

Tags: php, xml, api, http, curl

I'm trying to send some information to our CRM from a form on our site and am getting stuck on inserting the variables into the XML.  Here is a simplified version of my code.  Notice where I'm trying to insert the $email variable within the XML variable...which is not working.

```
<?php

$email = $_GET["email"];


$xml = '<xmlrequest>
<details>
    <emailaddress>$email</emailaddress>
    <mailinglist>8</mailinglist>
    <format>html</format>
    <confirmed>no</confirmed>
</details>
</xmlrequest>
';

 $ch = curl_init('http://mysite.com/xml.php');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
 $result = @curl_exec($ch);
 if ($result === false) {
echo "Error performing request";
 } else {
$xml_doc = simplexml_load_string($result);
header( "Location: http://mysite.com/confirmation?email=$email" ) ;

//echo 'Status is ', $xml_doc -> status, '<br/>';
 if ($xml_doc -> status == 'SUCCESS') {
    echo 'Data is ', $xml_doc -> data, '<br/>';

} else {
    echo 'Error is ', $xml_doc -> errormessage, '<br/>';
}
}

?>
```

If I just type in an email address value for the API works fine.  However, I'm clueless on how to pull this in dynamically from a PHP variable. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're not going to see that `echo` once you sent the header redirect..

Comment: I think a careful inspection of the code would have solved the problem here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string definition is bad
use this

```
$xml = "<xmlrequest>
<details>
    <emailaddress>{$email}</emailaddress>
    <mailinglist>8</mailinglist>
    <format>html</format>
    <confirmed>no</confirmed>
</details>
</xmlrequest>";
```

or this

```
$xml = '<xmlrequest>
<details>
    <emailaddress>' . $email . '</emailaddress>
    <mailinglist>8</mailinglist>
    <format>html</format>
    <confirmed>no</confirmed>
</details>
</xmlrequest>';
```

Because this variable probably can be various string I think it's better if you use `<![CDATA[]]>` section around the email.

Comment: PazsitZ - you are the man...the second snippet worked like a charm.  Cheers!